# The difference between static IP address and static routing

Tags: ip

I am kind of confused by these two terms: **static IP address** and **static routing**. Can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

`Static IP addresses` is manually assigned to a computer by an administrator.

`Static routing` is a form of routing that occurs when a router uses a manually-configured routing entry, rather than information from a dynamic routing traffic.

Reference :

1. [wiki Static routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_routing)